# stopping while true loop in discord.py with command

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Im making a simple crash gamble command in discord bot, but i don't know, when i use !crash money, how to stop it with !stop. I have a while True loop and i want to make somehow break the while true loop with the command !stop, i have no idea, how to make the command.

simplified code

```
@client.command()
async def crash(ctx, amount = None):
 multiplier = 1
 while True:
  multiplier += 0.2
  #here i would like something, when author of the crash command will write !stop, it will break the while true loop 
 win_amount = int(multiplier*amount)
```

Comment: why not just `async def stop(ctx): stop = True` then in the while loop just do `if stop: break` ?(note you need to make `stop` `gobal` and reference it as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply make a variable that tells when the stop command is run like so:

```
@client.command()
async def stop():
    global stopVar
    stopVar = True

@client.command()
async def crash(ctx, amount = None):
    global stopVar
    stopVar = False
    multiplier = 1
    while True:
    multiplier += 0.2
    if stopVar:
        break
    win_amount = int(multiplier*amount)
```

obviously if you want to make it where multiple people can play at once that will have to be added but making the variable user-dependant. Other features may be desired as well.

A simple way of making it author specific would be to add a dictionary to the `stop` function:

```
#example (not working code)
@client.command()
async def stop(ctx):
    global stopDict
    stopDict[ctx.message.author] = True
```